# How to test data saving on firestore GCP

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I implemented a DAO layer for persistence for my spring boot app destined to be deployed in GCP environement.
I'm not sure how i can test my persistence localy using the GCP firestore emulator.
especialy that i can't find any commands to display documents and there is no client that allows data query localy.
Any tips ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "host" end point your client library uses to the hostname:port of your locally-running emulator.

When you get the instance of your client you can set some config:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
 .setHost(<YOUR EMULATOR HOST HERE>)
   .setCredentials(credentials)
    .setProjectId(projectId)
    .build();
```